# Onboarding Process Deliverable

Tags: onboarding

I have started learning about user on-boarding. Not sure what on-boarding pattern to use, though. Also, what are the deliverables?

Comment: What all have you read/explored/researched so far? What is your understanding?

Comment: Have you gone through this?  https://material.io/design/communication/onboarding.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the onboarding process, I would say it depends on the industry you're working in.

I'm personnally trying to implement an onboarding process that looks like a tutorial from videogames (business webapp). Still, I have to do some research about it and I have to understand how people are feeling about our app and the efficiency of it.

I don't think there ONE perfect solution, it depends on your case.